# Angularjs how to create image gallery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs, maybe someone can help me to learn. I want to create an image gallery that has buttons to switch from one image to another.

how to create an image gallery with angularjs? 
and include a navigation bar?

Comment: Thank you help me to optimize the format.thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ha ha.I also think there no clear.I want to ask is to use angularjs write a button on the image.

Comment: @akonsu asks nothing, us guess

Comment: @rnrneverdies Ha ha.

Comment: Yeah good good......

Comment: @rnrneverdies thank you. I have been watching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-switch and ng-switch-when directives to select the visible picture. And after all put a navigation bar to change your selection using ng-click directive.

Look at this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSgcFy?p=preview).

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-switch on="selected" ng-init="selected=1">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="333px" height="277px" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="2">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="333px" height="277px" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="333px" height="277px" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="4">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="333px" height="277px" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <span class="number" ng-click="selected=1">1</span>
      <span class="number" ng-click="selected=2">2</span>
      <span class="number" ng-click="selected=3">3</span>
      <span class="number" ng-click="selected=4">4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wait a minute I also want to ask more, If I have more pictures Click on the Numbers to the corresponding picture. What should I do.

Comment: I'm sorry I have just a network problem. you said very GOOD.thanks.

Comment: yeah.yeah.you are right. I was watching.

Comment: @dblose before I understood wrong. hope you serve. greetings.

Comment: Yeah you see I will give you a accept it. I am a problem network. finally. Appreciation. Thank you.